# Crear If las veces que pida el usuario PHP

Tags: php

Hola a ver si me se explicar, lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:
La variable `$widgets` va a ser cualquier numero ya que eso lo va a colocar el usuario en el Plugin

Digamos que `$widgets = 3`

Y tengo esta función

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<?php
function comprobar_cf(){
    if (current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $status=get_option( "activate_deactivate" );
    $widgets = wp_unslash( get_option( "widgets"  ) );
    if($status == "1"){
        global $wpdb;
        $visitas = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT visitas FROM ".$this->plugin->table_name."");
        if($visitas == 0){
            $this->insertar_ip();
            header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
            header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            $this->click();
        }
        elseif($visitas == 1){
            $this->actualizar_visita();
            header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
            header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            $this->click();
        }
        elseif($visitas == 2){
            $this->actualizar_visita();
            header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
            header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            $this->click();
        }
    }
}
?>
<!-- end snipped -->
```

Este plugin es un rotador de URL, estoy usando una base de datos para guardar que link ya se ha enviado una visita anteriormente, digamos que hay 6 URL

```
012345
```

Si anteriormente ya se visitó la visita #2 esta vez le tocará a la visita #3
Pero ¿Y si son 10 URL ?
Así como lo tengo solo funciona si el Usuario elige que `$widgets = 3` quiero hacer una función que se creen los IF según el valor de `$widgets` espero me entiendan sino por favor pregunten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puesto que el código de tus tres if es idéntico, podrías hacerlo así:

Simplemente en vez de repetir el if las veces que sean necesarias, lo que hacemos es un sólo if en el que la condición se cumpla cuando se llegue a las visitas necesarias.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<?php
function comprobar_cf(){
    if (current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $status=get_option( "activate_deactivate" );
    $widgets = wp_unslash( get_option( "widgets"  ) );
    if($status == "1"){
        global $wpdb;
        $visitas = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT visitas FROM ".$this->plugin->table_name."");
        if($visitas <  $widgets){
            $this->insertar_ip();
            header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
            header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            $this->click();
        }
    }
}
?>
<!-- end snipped -->
```